# Valor por defecto en md-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy tratando de poner un valor por defecto a un md-autocomplete, pero no me es posible.

Necesito poder realizar esta función, puesto que tengo un servicio que me devuelve ciertos parámetros que se deberían completar automáticamente y, en caso de no existir, el usuario completar el formulario manualmente.

Os pongo el código actual, pero claro, no tengo nada de valores por defecto, por que no he encontrado ni si es posible (entiendo que si), pero no se si por la propia funcionalidad del md-autocomplete o no.

***Vista***

```
<md-autocomplete
   md-selected-item="ciudadItem"
   md-search-text="nombreCiudad"
   md-items="ciudad in obtenerCiudades(nombreCiudad)"
   md-item-text="ciudad.desCiudad"
   ng-model="NombreCiudadCups.valor"
   placeholder="Nombre ciudad..."
   name="Ciudad">
   <md-item-template>
     <span md-highlight-text="nombreCiudad">{{ciudad.desCiudad}}</span>
   </md-item-template>
   <md-not-found>
     Ciudad no encontrada.
   </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

***Controlador***

```
$scope.obtenerCiudades = function (text) {
    text = text.toUpperCase();
    var ret = $scope.ciudades.filter(function (d) {
        return d.desCiudad.startsWith(text);
    });
return ret;
};
```

`$scope.ciudades` es un simple json con un ciudades, no tiene ningún misterio, por eso no lo adjunto.

En este punto, se muestra bien todos los datos y busca bien, pero me falta el poder ponerle un valor por defecto, que el usuario luego podría borrar.

Answer (score 0):

**Solución**

Primero declarar en el controlado el item vacío.

```
$scope.ciudadItem = {};
```

Luego, en el momento que recibo valor del servicio, cargarlo.

```
$scope.ciudadItem = {
                        desCiudad: {
                            desCiudad: "Esta es la ciudad"
                        }
                    };
```

Para terminar, hice un pequeño ajuste en el template, para el valor

```
md-selected-item="ciudadItem.desCiudad"
```